# Firebase Functions - Delete data without knowing the key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: Data Structure]
I am inserting data in Firebase Realtime Database in a table with the above structure. The key of the data is auto-generated based on `push`. After several such entries are created, sometime due to certain conditions I may need to delete one of the entries. At the point of deleting the entry, I may know some of the values of the node that I want to delete like `createdAt` and `createdForPostID`. But I will not know the key as it was auto-generated using `push` feature of firebase database. A combination of `createdAt` and `createdForPostID` makes a unique combination and only one such entry should exist in the database.

***What would be the most efficient way to identify the entry without having to retrieve the entire node at `OUTBOUND`?***

The reason I am using `push` is because Firebase claims it to be efficient and not subject to write conflicts. I also rely on the auto-sorting by date/time offered by `push`.

If no efficient way can be found, then I will generate my own key using date/time stamp. But I am hoping that this is a problem that someone has solved before and hence can guide me.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to run a query to find the items that match your conditions.

Since you seem to have multiple properties in your conditions, and the Firebase Database can only query on a single property, you'll need to combine the values into a single property as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase).

Then you can run a query on that combined property and delete the items it returns:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("createForPostID-createdAt").equalTo("20171229_124904-20171230_200343");
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.remove();
})
```

Comment: Appreciate it, @frank-van-puffelen

Answer (score 0):

Given Frank's answer I realised, I needed to create a unique property as per his suggestion because I will need it to do the future query. But then it seemed that I may be better off using that unique property as the key instead of using `push`

So it seems from an overall perspective, it might be more efficient to create your own `key` instead of `push`, if the app needs both `create` and `delete` functions. Reliance on `push` makes sense only if data is being created and deletion is not a big functionality of your app.

So, in conclusion, for Firebase data, the most efficient way to do both data `create` and `delete` needs creation of a unique key on your own.